# Wordpress Linux on Azure marketplace doesn't working

Tags: azure, wordpress

Right after the installation the server always returns the error 502 Bad Gateway - nginx

This is the log

2021-01-07T01:01:29  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service.
Starting Log Tail -n 10 of existing logs ----
/home/LogFiles/__lastCheckTime.txt  (h t t p : / /refritec.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/__lastCheckTime.txt)01/06/2021 21:29:48

/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/2433a5b487bc-d26ae6de-22d3-4080-9a9e-885bc7f3eaee.txt  (h t t p : / /refritec.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/2433a5b487bc-d26ae6de-22d3-4080-9a9e-885bc7f3eaee.txt)
2021-01-06T21:30:57  Startup Request, url: /api/vfs/site/wwwroot/?_=1609967296424, method: GET, type: request, pid: 178,1,15, ScmType: None

/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/4484297e20b6-99d3ec14-a894-45a7-9d99-6789a1c31c38.txt  (h t t p : / /refritec.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/4484297e20b6-99d3ec14-a894-45a7-9d99-6789a1c31c38.txt)
2021-01-06T22:29:27  Startup Request, url: /api/logs/docker, method: GET, type: request, pid: 146,1,20, ScmType: None

/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/b3942923d997-f2525b2e-0c42-47d6-90b2-8fe719a0deee.txt  (h t t p : / /refritec.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/b3942923d997-f2525b2e-0c42-47d6-90b2-8fe719a0deee.txt)
2021-01-07T00:03:08  Startup Request, url: /api/vfs/site/wwwroot/?_=1609976744818, method: GET, type: request, pid: 161,1,4, ScmType: None

/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/bc4bb9da0ee8-b3949a1c-59f5-440b-ac4a-3aec3a89b4d9.txt  (h t t p : / /refritec.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/bc4bb9da0ee8-b3949a1c-59f5-440b-ac4a-3aec3a89b4d9.txt)
2021-01-06T23:58:13  Startup Request, url: /api/vfs/site/wwwroot/?_=1609976744815, method: GET, type: request, pid: 127,1,16, ScmType: None

/home/LogFiles/2021_01_06_lw0sdlwk00002A_default_docker.log  (h t t p : / /refritec.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/2021_01_06_lw0sdlwk00002A_default_docker.log)
2021-01-06T23:58:51.619267660Z 2021-01-06 23:58:51,509 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 119
2021-01-06T23:58:51.804316173Z 2021-01-06 23:58:51,794 INFO spawned: 'sshd' with pid 120
2021-01-06T23:58:51.993869394Z 2021-01-06 23:58:51,959 INFO spawned: 'watch-fpm-socket' with pid 121
2021-01-06T23:58:52.532445506Z 2021-01-06 23:58:52,530 INFO success: php-fpm entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2021-01-06T23:58:52.590188703Z 2021-01-06 23:58:52,580 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2021-01-06T23:58:52.678840153Z 2021-01-06 23:58:52,677 INFO success: sshd entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2021-01-06T23:58:52.979378062Z 2021-01-06 23:58:52,976 INFO success: watch-fpm-socket entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2021-01-06T23:59:07.114135546Z 2021-01-06 23:59:07,113 INFO exited: sshd (exit status 0; expected)

/home/LogFiles/2021_01_06_lw0sdlwk00002A_docker.log  (h t t p : / /refritec.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/2021_01_06_lw0sdlwk00002A_docker.log)
2021-01-06T23:50:13.805Z INFO  - Pulling image from Docker hub: http://mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/wordpress-alpine-php:0.72
2021-01-06T23:50:17.115Z INFO  - 0.72 Pulling from appsvc/wordpress-alpine-php
2021-01-06T23:50:17.366Z INFO  -  Digest: sha256:093ddec5b61ed66e8642da89928b611454cc57f091a0d7c3d9e10835c16d5896
2021-01-06T23:50:17.368Z INFO  -  Status: Image is up to date for http://mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/wordpress-alpine-php:0.72
2021-01-06T23:50:18.012Z INFO  - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 0 Minutes and 3 Seconds
2021-01-06T23:50:18.457Z INFO  - Starting container for site
2021-01-06T23:50:18.458Z INFO  - docker run -d -p 8184:80 --name refritec_4_aa081bdf -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=true -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=refritec -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e PORT=80 -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=http://refritec.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=27a8387a29d0e883736126cb444aced9b0c7daa310ed6e78e304c09e4cac392e -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 http://mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/wordpress-alpine-php:0.72
2021-01-06T23:50:39.855Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container refritec_4_aa081bdf for site refritec
2021-01-06T23:50:49.864Z INFO  - Container refritec_4_aa081bdf for site refritec initialized successfully and is ready to serve requests.

/home/LogFiles/2021_01_07_lw0sdlwk00002A_default_docker.log  (h t t p : / /refritec.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/2021_01_07_lw0sdlwk00002A_default_docker.log)
2021-01-07T00:00:24.019623691Z 2021-01-07 00:00:23,992 INFO spawned: 'php-fpm' with pid 118
2021-01-07T00:00:24.183214889Z 2021-01-07 00:00:24,145 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 119
2021-01-07T00:00:24.214397508Z 2021-01-07 00:00:24,212 INFO spawned: 'sshd' with pid 120
2021-01-07T00:00:24.309606065Z 2021-01-07 00:00:24,263 INFO spawned: 'watch-fpm-socket' with pid 121
2021-01-07T00:00:24.965113958Z 2021-01-07 00:00:24,956 INFO success: php-fpm entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2021-01-07T00:00:25.423051506Z 2021-01-07 00:00:25,421 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2021-01-07T00:00:25.452002856Z 2021-01-07 00:00:25,423 INFO success: sshd entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2021-01-07T00:00:25.460312670Z 2021-01-07 00:00:25,452 INFO success: watch-fpm-socket entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2021-01-07T00:00:32.937405640Z 2021-01-07 00:00:32,928 INFO exited: sshd (exit status 0; expected)

/home/LogFiles/nginx/access.log  (h t t p : / /refritec.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/nginx/access.log)

/home/LogFiles/nginx/error.log  (h t t p : / /refritec.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/nginx/error.log)2021/01/06 21:33:12 [error] 163#163: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.16.4.1, server: _, request: "GET /robots933456.txt HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "127.0.0.1:7038"2021/01/06 21:33:12 [error] 163#163: *3 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.16.4.1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "http://refritec.azurewebsites.net", referrer: "h t t p : / /portal.azure.com"2021/01/06 22:21:24 [error] 141#141: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.16.4.1, server: _, request: "GET /robots933456.txt HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "127.0.0.1:1392"2021/01/06 22:21:24 [crit] 141#141: *3 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.16.4.1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "http://refritec.azurewebsites.net", referrer: "h t t p : / /portal.azure.com"2021/01/06 23:50:10 [error] 141#141: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.16.4.1, server: _, request: "GET /robots933456.txt HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "127.0.0.1:4836"2021/01/06 23:50:49 [error] 141#141: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.16.4.1, server: _, request: "GET /robots933456.txt HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "127.0.0.1:8184"2021/01/06 23:50:49 [error] 141#141: *3 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.16.4.1, server: _, request: "GET /install HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "http://refritec.azurewebsites.net"2021/01/06 23:58:52 [error] 141#141: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.16.4.1, server: _, request: "GET /robots933456.txt HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "127.0.0.1:3981"2021/01/06 23:58:53 [error] 141#141: *3 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.16.4.1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "http://refritec.azurewebsites.net"

/home/LogFiles/nginx/php-error.log  (h t t p : / /refritec.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/nginx/php-error.log)

/home/LogFiles/supervisor/supervisord.log  (h t t p : / /refritec.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/supervisor/supervisord.log)
2021-01-07 00:00:22,853 INFO supervisord started with pid 116
2021-01-07 00:00:23,992 INFO spawned: 'php-fpm' with pid 118
2021-01-07 00:00:24,145 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 119
2021-01-07 00:00:24,212 INFO spawned: 'sshd' with pid 120
2021-01-07 00:00:24,263 INFO spawned: 'watch-fpm-socket' with pid 121
2021-01-07 00:00:24,956 INFO success: php-fpm entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2021-01-07 00:00:25,421 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2021-01-07 00:00:25,423 INFO success: sshd entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2021-01-07 00:00:25,452 INFO success: watch-fpm-socket entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2021-01-07 00:00:32,928 INFO exited: sshd (exit status 0; expected)

/home/LogFiles/webssh/pm2.log  (h t t p : / /refritec.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/webssh/pm2.log)

Ending Log Tail of existing logs ---
Starting Live Log Stream ---

Comment: Unless you provide more information your question will be closed. Show us what investigation you have done so far, what do the logs say, what have you tried that did not work?

Comment: Go to azure marketplace and try to install the WordPress Linux, it will always fail

Comment: If you would like assistance with the problem you need to provide the details, were not going to go and install this just to get the error message

Comment: Hi @SamCogan, I think it is something relevant for Azure, it is the most use application on the internet and the installation simply doesn't work. My next shoot will be to try to install on GCP or Digital Ocean. I know it is a problem on Marketplace because the Windows version of the WP it is working, I have about 10 apps installed. But the cost is 4 times higher.

Comment: I am sorry @SamCogan I thought you would work on Azure. My bad, I mixed because I am talking to the support also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure confirmed it is a bug on East region. The solution to this problem was just use the East2 region.